# Node.js server CORS Failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, express, pm2

I have a 1-click LAMP Droplet from Digital Ocean (Ubuntu). I’ve installed Node.js on it and I’ve added an express.js application.
With PM2 I made it run successfully on port 3002, if I use sudo pm2 list I can see that is online. I’m trying to reach endpoints on this running express.js app from my React website (which is on the same server), but I get CORS Failed as I see on Network tab(browser inspector window).
[Network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QchkS.png)

My express.js app has cors:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
```

And in React, I’m doing the request like this:

```
await fetch('https://localhost:3002/contacts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Ubuntu version: 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
PM2 version: 5.1.2
Node.js version: 16.13.1

Is something that I’m missing?

Thanks alot.

Comment: What error in the console about CORS?

Comment: Instead of `sudo pm2 list` you can just run `npx pm2 list`. It's the typical way to do it, and it's the built-in way. Also, `express.json()` is *deprecated*. Use body parser instead. Finally, if your React page is on the _same_ server, you shouldn't even need CORS for your fetch to work, since it is an internal URL. Try changing the URL of fetch to `/contacts`. On top of that, are you sure it's `https://localhost:3002`, or is it just `http://localhost:3002`? `https` won't work locally unless you have special configurations.

Comment: You cannot put `localhost` URLs in client-side code because the browser will try to load the resource from *your own computer*. Just try `fetch("/contacts")` instead.

Comment: How can I use fetch("/contacts") with the port 3002? Because I believe that the React app is using a different port.